# redirect all non www to www. for Cakephp site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

Hi allm i'm having some issues in redirecting the non www pages to the www. pages for my cakephp site.

I've tried

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

My cakephp app resides in a subfolder. eg. `www.domain.com/my`.

i've added the above code to the root folder, `www.domain.com/`

any suggestions? thanks?

*update

This my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

i'm getting an extra `webroot/index.php?url=` inserted into the url. Instead of `www.domain.com/my/apple`, i'm getting `www.domain.com/my/webroot/index.php?url=apple`

thanks to all once again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is not quite right. See below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] # <-- Mind the 'L'!

RewriteRule ^$ webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! But there's still a problem. The urls are getting redirected but i'm getting an extra "webroot/index.php?url=" inserted into the url. Instead of www.domain.com/my/apple, i'm getting www.domain.com/my/webroot/index.php?url=apple

Comment: i realised there's a default line of "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]" in the .htacess in the file. I can't remove that line as the pages will show an error.

Comment: just put the default cake rules under then (I updated my answer to show the result)

Comment: @mobz now that you've got it working, you should consider pointing your Apache webroot to APP/webroot instead of your APP root directory. You can put the rewrite rules for the www domain in the .htaccess file there. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

if domain is .co.uk

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [NC] 
   RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

   RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below code below and it worked for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^gigsadda\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.gigsadda.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```