# Apache redirecting in CakePHP: old pages ending with .php to new ones

Tags: apache, cakephp, redirect, web

I have a new CakePHP site, and I wish to redirect some old urls to new ones.

- /contact.php to /contact
- /news.php to /
- /courses.php to /courses

I've tried 301 apache redirect inside the .htaccess (the root one, inside /app and inside /app/webroot, but none worked.

I also wanted to redirect all non www urls to www. I looked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806901/redirect-all-non-www-to-www-for-cakephp-site) but the example didn't worked for me. I'm using CakePHP 2.0.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CakePHP is installed into root you should be able to redirect these URLs into correct ones with routes.php. Take a look into redirect routing documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing

Comment: Thank you, I've just done the redirects from the .php to normal controllers within the routes.php. But I havent't figured out how to redirect non www to www :(

Answer (score 0):

is important that your server have mod_rewrite enabled.
You can then modify the url in app/config/routes.php

Although still not clear to me as you had before contact.php type routes